# setAdapter compiler error from listview to my custom adapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm not sure what's wrong with this segment of code:

```
    mylistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, rowItems);
    mylistview.setAdapter(adapter);

    mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

The line causing an error is mylistview.setAdapter(adapter). 
CustomAdapter is a java class with the constructor defined as so:

```
Context context;
List<RowItem> rowItems;

CustomAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> rowItems){
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItems = rowItems;
}
```

The error I'm getting is: 
'setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' in 'android.widget.ListView' cannot be applied to '(com.name.app.CustomAdapter)'

I have no idea what's causing this error and would greatly appreciate some insight as to why I can't set the adapter of my custom adapter to the listview. Thanks.

Comment: Your `CustomAdapter` class must implement the `ListAdapter` interface, either directly, or by extending another `Adapter` class. What does your class definition look like?

Comment: For CustomAdapter?

Comment: I use this function for the view:

Comment: public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

Comment: and return the new view convertView

Comment: No. What does the first line of the class say? `public class CustomAdapter ... ???`?

Comment: Oh shoot, nothing else

Comment: let me try extends BaseAdapter, thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

Context context;

ArrayList<String> list;

LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

SpinnerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list)
{
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    this.list = list;

    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return list.indexOf(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_s,null);

    TextView client = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.client);

    client.setText(list.get(position).toString());

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The setAdapter requires android.widget.ListAdapter. It looks like you CustomAdapter class needs to implement the ListAdapter interface